# What is the "." called in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, terminology

I know what it's used for, I know what it's called in language terms, but what is the official name of the period/dot used in Javascript/jQuery?

Thanks!

Comment: "dot notation", I guess...

Answer (score 4):

I've generally heard of it as a [property accessor](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors) in JS as well as other languages.
The [ES5 spec](https://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1) refers to it as such. If you want to refer to the specific character, dot notation or operator is commonly used when discussing syntax.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The ES5 spec refers to it simply as the dot in "dot notation," along with `[]` for "bracket notation" under the heading [Property Accessors](https://es5.github.io/#x11.2.1).

Comment: I agree with the statement of Shawn.

Answer (score 0):

The dot is the GET operator in Javascript, in ES2015 (the new standard of javascript) you can override what the get operator does for specific objects.
Example:

```
var target = {};
var handler = {
  get: function (receiver, name) {
    return `Hello, ${name}!`;
  }
};

var p = new Proxy(target, handler);
p.world === "Hello, world!";
```

Answer (score 0):

someone call it `dot notation` and someone else `dot operator`.

Comment: Uhm ok, but i think it is an answer, is not a comment.